# Make hidden elements visible after submitting form

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

Currently **info,stat and foo** elements are hidden. When I submit the form, it doesn't make them visible.
If I use this **unhide()** function inside the `<button onclick="unhide()"></button>`, it works properly. But it doesn't work inside the form.

How can the **unhide()** function make these elements visible after submitting the form?

```
<style>
                    #info {
                        visibility: hidden;
                    }
                    #stat {
                        visibility: hidden;
                    }
                    #foo {
                        visibility: hidden;
                    }
            </style>
            
            <script>
            
                    function unhide() {
                    var x = document.getElementById("info");
                    var y = document.getElementById("stat");
                    var z = document.getElementById("foo");
                    
                        if (x.style.visibility === "hidden" && x.style.visibility === "hidden" && x.style.visibility === "hidden") {
                            x.style.visibility = "visible";
                            y.style.visibility = "visible";
                            z.style.visibility = "visible";
                        } 
                        else{
                            x.style.visibility = "hidden";
                            y.style.visibility = "hidden";
                            z.style.visibility = "hidden";
                        }
                    }
        
             </script>
           
            
                <form method="GET" onsubmit="unhide()" action="../index.js" class="justify-center flex p-6">
                    <input class="mt-4 text-lg p-3 text-white rounded-l-md border-white border-2 bg-gray-900  outline-none" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Enter country">
                    <input class="mt-4 py-3 px-6 font-bold rounded-r-md text-lg cursor-pointer" value="search" id="submit" type="submit">
                    
                </form>
```

Comment: I think your if clause is not very good, (x.style.visibility === "hidden" && x.style.visibility === "hidden" && x.style.visibility === "hidden"), is it correct ?

Ithink you must write (x.style.visibility === "hidden" && y.style.visibility === "hidden" && z.style.visibility === "hidden")

Comment: function is executing properly outside the form. there's not issue with function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you submit a form, the default behaviour is to submit the data to the url specified in the `action` attribute. This triggers a page reload.

So your hidden elements are probably becoming visible, but then the page reloads so quickly, you're not able to see them before they become invisible again.

To prevent this default behaviour, include an `event` as a parameter to the `onsubmit` eventHandler, and in the first line of your code, insert the line `event.preventDefault()`.

This will allow you to submit the form data, but will not trigger a page reload, so your hidden elements will now be visible.

You can look at the snippet below:

```js
function unhide(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var x = document.getElementById("info");
  var y = document.getElementById("stat");
  var z = document.getElementById("foo");

  if (x.style.visibility === "hidden" && y.style.visibility === "hidden" && z.style.visibility === "hidden") {
    x.style.visibility = "visible";
    y.style.visibility = "visible";
    z.style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    x.style.visibility = "hidden";
    y.style.visibility = "hidden";
    z.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}
```

```css
#info {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#stat {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#foo {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<form method="GET" onsubmit="unhide(event)" action="/" class="justify-center flex p-6">
  <input class="mt-4 text-lg p-3 text-white rounded-l-md border-white border-2 bg-gray-900  outline-none" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Enter country">
  <input class="mt-4 py-3 px-6 font-bold rounded-r-md text-lg cursor-pointer" value="search" id="submit" type="submit">
</form>

<div id="info"> This is some info </div>
<div id="stat"> Stat </div>
<div id="foo"> Some random information </div>
```